# Opera displays viewport-sized elements incorrectly

Tags: css

I used vw values for height/width of elements, Chrome displays them right, but it looks completely different in Opera. Black background elements.
I guess you don't need any css lines, because you can pretty much see it by yourself:
http://meanwhile.today

What can possible be wrong? Do I need to use additional css for Opera?

Comment: The menu and similar stuf on the site looks weird when making the browser window smaller to. Chrome 35

Comment: @AlfredLarsson I haven't done media queries yet. But it would be very nice if you post a screenshot and tell me about your screen size and desktop resolution.